# How to replace chars and remove no in Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this content in my cell in Excel '`TS_Bud03A`'
I have other cell content with content that should not be touched by bullet no 1 below. For instance cells with `P_Har02b`

I would like one nested formula for 2 operations

1. Substitute 'TS_' with 'TVS_'
2. Remove the last letter after the 2 digit number if one exists

For the first operation I have made this formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(K12;"TS_";"TVS_")
```

It works. But how do I nest another substitute, that will remove the last letter (any case - if it exists) after the 2 digit number?

By combining the 2 answers below I think I almost got it. Like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(LEFT(K15;LEN(K15)--ISNUMBER(RIGHT(K15;1)*1)-1);2;0;"V");"TS_";"TVS_")
```

But it still changes this `P_Bud04a` to this `PV_Bud04` and this is wrong. The P cells must be untouched.
Any ideas how I can remove the replace that adds V part of the formula I have here in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following works for you:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)--ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,1)*1)-1),2,0,"V")
```

---

- `REPLACE(<string>,2,0,"V")` - Acts like pasting a substring into a string.
- `LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-<number>` - Our string in the first parameter of `REPLACE()` has to be either the full length or minus one. That number is still to be determined.
- `-ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,1)*1)-1` - Will check if the last character in `A1` is numeric and therfor will return a boolean value `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Their equivalent numeric values are `1` and `0`. So if `TRUE` it will return `0`, if `FALSE`, it will return `1`.

---

**EDIT:** After your comment I understand your data does not always start with `TS_`, therefor you need to simply swap `REPLACE()` with `SUBSTITUTE()`, e.g:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)--ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,1)*1)-1),"TS_","TVS_")
```

Comment: This seemed to work with my first example cell. But I also have other cells with other content, that should not be touched. Please read the first part of my question again. I have added the new content. And it explains why I cannot use this formula in its present configuration. The first replace statement must test for 'TS'.

Comment: Ah right, I thought your data might have been staticly starting with `TS_`. I've edited the answer @Excaliburst

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(K12;2));SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(K12;LEN(K12)-2);"TS_";"TVS_");SUBSTITUTE(K12;"TS_";"TVS_"))`

I think this is what you need. It first checks if the right last 2 characters are a number (added `--` to convert number stored as text to number). Then, if true, remove the last 2 characters and substitute like you mentioned, or, if false substitute according to your formula without removing the last 2 characters.

Comment: Hi User...,
It works with replacing command. But not the removal of last letter (second bulletpoint).
and no errors are thrown.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my task. I need to check if there are any letters at the end. And if so, remove them. And leave the 2 numbers. So the boolean test is off somehow.

Comment: Ah, I read it now. I interpreted it to remove the 2 last digits if they're number.

Comment: Are the 2 digits followed by the character always at the end of your data?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it. I just removed the V between quotes, so as to not put any new content into the cell. And it worked.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(LEFT(K12;LEN(K12)--ISNUMBER(RIGHT(K12;1)*1)-1);2;0;"");"TS_";"TVS_")
```

Thanks guys

Comment: See the edit on my answer. You made it too complicated on yourself. Also, don't forget to accept/upvote answers if they been helpfull.